# Ionic - $http.get() not sending Authorization Header

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, ionic-framework

Ionic App Not Sending Authorization Header. The Header Values Are Simply Not There Even though the Authorization Header Is Listed Among The Allowed Headers.
I Am Using NodeJS Express And MongoDB as A Backend Here Are My CORS Headers

```
    <code>
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
      'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers',
      'X-Authorization-Token, Authorization');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
    );

   And Here Is My AuthInterceptor


    return {
      request: function(config) {
        var token = authToken.getToken();

        if (token) {
          config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;

        }
        return config;
      },
      response: function(response) {
        return response;
      }
    };

My $http

        return $http(options).success(function(response) {
          self.currUser = response.profile;
          if (_.contains(response.profile.roles, 'admin') ||
            !((_.contains(response.profile.roles, 'lecturer')) || (_.contains(
              response.profile.roles, 'evaluator')))) {
            $state.go('admin');
          }
        })
</code>
```

Comment: won't get much help if you don't show the code used to set the headers

Comment: is `authToken.getToken()` synchronous? Does it return a valid token? If it is asynchronous you have a problem

Comment: no its from localstorage

Comment: i mean yes its from localstorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. The only way I figured out to solve it was by adding:

```
"proxies": [
{
  "path": "/<your local url>",
  "proxyUrl": "http://<remote_url>"
}
],
```

to my ionic.project file.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass auth header before making $http call. I have used in this way and this worked for me for API auth,

```
$http.defaults.headers.get = { 'x-username' User.email,
                           'x-token':authToken.getToken(), 
                           'Content-Type':'application/json'};

$http.get(URL+'/api).then(function(res){console.log('success')});
```

Hope this is helpful for you.